# How to get the attributes of a button after button has been called

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok so I made an account just for this because it is my College project and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Basically I am trying to create an interface for a Enigma machine and I have laid out everything where I want it but I am having trouble getting the buttons to print text to a textbox. Because I have it in a loop I am not individually setting each button to print something and if I try using the counter with a list it wont work becasue it always prints the last value in the list. Heres my code:

```
    from Tkinter import *

buttonlist = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]

master = Tk()
tempval = 0
Grid.rowconfigure(master,0,weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(master,0,weight=1)

def val_click(val):
    current_output = outputtext.get()
    inputtext.delete(0, END)
    inputtext.insert(0, current_output+str(val))


textlabel = Label(master, text="INPUT", fg="black")
textlabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
textlabel2 = Label(master, text="OUPUT", fg="black")
textlabel2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=10)
inputtext = Entry(master, width=50, bg="light blue")
inputtext.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=10)
outputtext = Entry(master, width=50, bg="light yellow")
outputtext.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=10)
file = open("Tkinter information.txt", "r")
readlines = file.readlines()

for s in range(0,31):
    buttonting = str((readlines[5]).split(",")[tempval])
    buttonlist[s] = Button(master, text=str((readlines[0]).split(",")[tempval]), command=lambda: val_click("THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PRINT THE TEXT PART OF THE BUTTON"), width=str((readlines[2]).split(",")[tempval]), height=1, bg=str((readlines[1]).split(",")[tempval]))
    buttonlist[s].grid(row=(readlines[3]).split(",")[tempval][0], column=(readlines[3]).split(",")[tempval][1], sticky=N+S+E+W, columnspan=(readlines[4]).split(",")[tempval])
    tempval = tempval + 1
    print buttonlist[s]


inputtext = Label(master, text="Rotor1", fg="black")
inputtext.grid(row=10, column=1, columnspan=2)
inputtext = Label(master, text="Rotor2", fg="black")
inputtext.grid(row=10, column=4, columnspan=2)
inputtext = Label(master, text="Rotor3", fg="black")
inputtext.grid(row=10, column=7, columnspan=2)
textbox = Entry(master, width=50, bg="light yellow")
textbox.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=3)
textbox = Entry(master, width=50, bg="light yellow")
textbox.grid(row=11, column=3, columnspan=4)
textbox = Entry(master, width=50, bg="light yellow")
textbox.grid(row=11, column=7, columnspan=3)
```

mainloop()

This part is from a notepad where it is pulling the information from:

```
Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U,I,O,P,A,S,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,Z,X,C,V,B,N,M,SPACE,CLEAR,ENCRYPT,SET ROTOR,SET PLUGBOARD,
light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,light green,red,light blue,yellow,green,
12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,70,72,74,76
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2
button001,button002,button003,button004,button005,button006,button007,button008,button009,button010,button011,button012,button013,button014,button015,button016,button017,button018,button019,button020,button021,button022,button023,button024,button025,button026,button027,button028,button029,button030,button031
```

So I had an idea of trying to get the text of the button and have that what it will print but I have not idea how to get the text of a button. What I mean is say if the button for "A" is pressed it will print A in the textbox but I don't know how to get the text attribute of the button pressed. If anybody knows how please reply thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to "PRINT THE TEXT PART OF THE BUTTON", or are you saying you want to print whatever character the button represents? In other words, is it important that you start by getting the label of the button, or is it ok if the string used for the button is also used for the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lambda that has the value "baked in" (in computer terms: "bound"). For example:

```
foo = "x"
Button(..., command= lambda the_value=foo: print "the value is " + the_value)
```

In your code it would look something like this:

```
for s in range(0,31):
    ...
    s = str((readlines[0]).split(",")[tempval])
    buttonlist[s] = Button(master, text=s, command=lambda value=s: val_click(value), ...)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I didn't think you could create variables within the button creation line. Got it working now so again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
# You don't have to type "" every time, use *
buttonlist = [""]*4

# Create a StringVariable for the label
textvar = StringVar()
# Set it to 'INPUT'
textvar.set('INPUT')
# Create the Label using the StringVariable
textlabel = Label(master, textvariable=textvar, fg="black").pack(fill='both')

# Loop to make the Buttons
for i in range(4):
    # Create a StringVariable for each of the buttons
    buttonlist[i] = StringVar()
    # Set it to anything you want (I set it to the number)
    buttonlist[i].set(str(i))
    # Create the button, use the textvariable and create the command to set the textvar of the label to the text of the button
    # Note that the i=i in the lambda function is very important, if you miss this you will always get the value of the last button
    Button(master, textvariable=buttonlist[i], command=lambda i=i: textvar.set(buttonlist[i].get())).pack(fill='both')


master.mainloop()
```

EDIT: After reading Bryan Oakley's answer I realize the StringVariables for the buttons are not necessary. I do think the StringVariable for the Entry might still be a good idea. I'd probably do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

# Create a StringVariable for the label
textvar = StringVar()
# Set it to 'INPUT'
textvar.set('INPUT')
# Create the Entry using the StringVariable
inputtext = Entry(master, width=50, textvariable=textvar, bg="light blue", justify='center').pack(fill='both')

def val_click(val):
    textvar.set(val)
    # Any other things you want to do here

strings = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# Loop to make the Buttons
for val in strings:
    # Make sure val is a string
    val=str(val)
    # Create the button, use the value and create the command to send the text to val_click
    Button(master, text=val, command=lambda t=val: val_click(t)).pack(fill='both')

master.mainloop()
```